# Everything Wrong with 1.9.1 and 1.9.2

Tags: extensions, theme, upgrade

i have a problem after i upgrade to 1.9.1 and 1.9.2.

All the extensions and themes have problems after the update, first my pay plug-in (payU) don’t notify the purchase, all the extensions configurations can’t access by my other admin users and my theme don’t show the products on the homepage.

I thought that upgrading to the 1.9.2 version problems will be fixed but it will worse. Now all the extensions can’t see on “my account” page and the theme can’t show anything, include the main banner.

I’m really amateur on this, but, what happened? Some permissions maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 1.9.2.2 uses white lists to display blocks and variables in the CMS pages. Make sure you add you product block to the white list under `system > permissions > blocks`. Another thing to note some 3rd party module will break due to incompatibility. Basically the 1.9.2.2 is the same as 1.9.1 but with the SUPEE-6788 patch installed plus some other patches. You should check the following list and see if you modules are on here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHJL6D6xm3vD349DJsDF88FBI_6PZvx_u3FioC_1-rg/edit#gid=0

[https://info2.magento.com/rs/318-XBX-392/images/SUPEE-6788-Technical Details.pdf](https://info2.magento.com/rs/318-XBX-392/images/SUPEE-6788-Technical%20Details.pdf)

Comment: ohhh man, i think that i love you, i don't know that permissions. i allowed all the blocks and everithing works fine (except for some bugs, but not is the end of the world)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well there might be some issues with the plugins. There are few bugs in 1.9.2 but not at the level you have mentioned. Try reinstalling the plugins again.Hope this helps